# password_verify is not Matching the password on the db password

Tags: php

Please tell me whats wrong i'm doing

[Its showing errorflase error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIhCd.png)

Comment: add the code to the question rather than an image of your code

Comment: you store password in database like a plain text?

Comment: I can not see any wrong with your posted code. But how do you use password_hash() at registration?

Comment: you go to all the trouble to use proper password validation techniques but leave your code wide open to sql inection which sort of defeats the object of the exercise somewhat

Answer (score 1):

There are no issues with the code. 
Make sure the columns length is long enough to accomodate the hash; that is usually an error many make. 
And, recheck the code you are using to save the password.

Comment: Ya you are right column length is not is not long enough is working now thank you

Comment: would you mind marking this accepted? @amitsingh

Answer (score -1):

Try out if all the letters are correct including the uppercase and lowercase. Also try using equalsignore to ignore case sensitive texts.

Answer (score -1):

Try password_verify manually including the hash variable (eg. for testing) 
make sure you are enclosing the hash variable in single quotes (') and not double quotes (").

PHP parses anything  starts with a $ and inside " quotes as a variable:

reference and further details:
[password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)